# Connect C# to Java Class via HTTP

Tags: c#, java, http

Tell me if this is crazy.

There exists a Java class file on a server.  Is there any way to send commands to the class via HTTP in C#?

I'm sorry if I am completely missing the boat on this one, but it is Friday and I need a vacation.

If this isn't possible, could someone please fill in the logical gap.  What else is needed?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how this Java Class file is running if at all ? Having a file on a disk is all you are describing here on the Java side.

Answer (score 0):

How about SOAP, or JSON & REST Web Services?

http://java.sun.com/webservices/

*"The Metro Web Services stack delivers secure, reliable, transactional interoperability between Java EE and .Net 3.0 to help you build, deploy, and maintain Composite Applications for your Service Oriented Architecture. Metro provides ease-of-development features, support for W3C and WS-I standards such as SOAP and WSDL, asynchronous client and server, and databinding through JAXB 2.0."*